# echo is Printing PHP-Control-Characters in the wrong way

Tags: php, html, echo

*(Edit: Sure you can find the answer on the other question (SOMEWHERE), but it's not exactly duplicate. My situation is different.)*

I'm totally beginner level in PHP. This code in my "test.html" is for me absolutely straight-forward:

```
<html>
    <body bgcolor="ffff00">
    <?php
        echo '<hr>hello world<hr>';
    ?>  
    </body>
</html>
```

I get this page:

[image]

This isn't the first time I had this issue. Last time I solved it and now I don't know how. Why is it printing me the closing apostrophe and semicolon and the closing php-tag-end? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: PHP isn't running. if you view the source you'll likely see `<?php echo '` is still there. The `<` in `<?php` is rendering as HTML and is escaped by the `<hr>`

Comment: Sorry I just saw that your file is `.html` for it to run php code it must be a `.php` file

Comment: The cause of what @IsThisJavascript correctly pointed out simply is: you named your file ``test.html``, but usually http servers are configured such that they only execute php if the file name ends in ``*.php``.

Comment: Indeed. This may just be because you've called the file `test.html` rather than `test.php`, but there could be other reasons why your PHP interpreter isn't actually running at all... You need to be running your code through a web server with a PHP interpreter configured.

Comment: Wow. What is wrong with stack? How is the question bad? Is it too noobish for you?

Comment: I get the feeling some people try to make SO a place for "experts" by downvoting simple questions.  So have an upvote from me; you gave details, and I believe questions like this are helpful to others.

Comment: I didn't downvote but you probably got downvoted because it's a duplicate. The question was asked in a good manner following the MVCE tho so I wouldn't say a downvote is warranted but a close flag for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should save the file as `.php` not `.html` if you have php code.

Comment: And likely ensure PHP is running.